# Shuffling the training data for machine learning models

Tags: machine-learning

**- For which algorithms is it necessary or at least important to shuffle the training data?**

For example, compare regression, bagging algorithms, boosting algorithms and neural nets regarding this.

Comment: @SeanOwen, I do not think that we need this kind of intervention here on datascience.stackexchange; already we cannot ask more general questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: The question is not off-topic, nor is it too general; it's too broad because it's three questions. Further, you say you know an answer to them, but want something more. You don't elaborate what else you're looking for. For these several reasons, this question needs to be edited and improved before it is right for a StackExchange site.

Comment: @SeanOwen, is it ok now? I removed the additional questions and my parenthesis about what I know about my question. My point regarding the former was that I am not so ignorant about shuffling but I would like a more complete and formal answer.

Comment: Basically, for stochastic and batch approaches that you attempt to minimise a typical cost function, you need to shuffle your data. The reason is simply due to letting your learning approach investigate different regions of the cost-weight space by changing the gradients. This will be done by shuffling data.

Comment: @Media, thank you for your comment. Yes, what you say makes absolutely sense. In this regard, then **shuffling should be done before applying algorithms such as random forest, xgboost and neural nets which introduce some randomness and/or take data into batches. Is this right?** (I find this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/291542/do-we-need-shuffle-the-entries-before-training-gbdt-by-xgboost/354287#comment702618_354287 quite relevant to my question)

Comment: It depends. Suppose you want to apply a neural network and you have a data set with a moderated size which enables you to apply gradient descent using the entire data set each time. In this situation, it is not nessary that you shuffle. The reason is that even you shuffle, the gradients won't change. On the contrary, for the batch solutions, your approach is a kind of stochastic, it means that your derivative terms don't nescessarily lead you to a correct direction. But after applying some steps you can almost be sure that you are not in a wrong path to recede the an extremum.

Comment: @Media, cool, yes, that's right! What about random forests and boosting algorithms (e.g. xgboost) specifically? (you can write all these things in an answer below if you want and I can upvote it etc)

Comment: The answer part is closed for `put on hold` questions! You can generalise the idea to other things. For tree-based algorithms, I guess it is not important. What you do there is a kind of aggregating after investigating *all* inputs.

Comment: @Media, cool. By the way, please keep in mind the comments at this answer (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/354287/193309) regarding bagging and/or boosting algorithms.

Comment: One reason why my question is still `put on hold` is because now at Austin. Texas is still 08:52am so @SeanOwen has not logged in here yet!!

Comment: It's a kind of sampling method. We sample to find a statistic. Coming from population to sample jargons!